# Como crear y acceder a multiples List desde thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, controller, thymeleaf

Buen día.

Vengo comenzando con lo que es spring-boot, tengo una consulta que no se como resolver. Les comento...
Tengo un controller mediante un modelo llamado persona, algo así.

```
@Controller
public class PersonasController {
    @Autowired
    private PersonasService servicio;
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("lista", servicio.getLista());
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Me crea una lista a la cual puedo acceder sin problemas desde thymeleaf, pero cuando pretendo crear otra (desde otro controller) no me permite acceder, la misma la creo de la siguiente manera, pero con un modelo llamado usuarios.

```
@Controller
public class UsuariosController {
    @Autowired
    private UsuariosService servicio_users;

    @RequestMapping("/usuarios/")
    public String index(Model model2){
        model2.addAttribute("lista_usuarios", servicio_users.getLista());
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Para leer la lista y colocarla en mi html a través de thymeleaf lo hago de la siguiente manera.

```
<tr th:each="tmp:${lista}">
<td th:text="${tmp.id}"></td>
<td th:text="${tmp.nombre}"></td>
<td th:text="${tmp.correo}"></td>
</tr>
```

Cuando me refiero a la list **lista** me carga la información, pero si intento cargar la información de **lista_usuarios** no me carga.

Como comenté vengo comenzando, espero me ayuden, saludos.